# jquery.raty.js works localy but doesn't work on heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, raty

I'm using raty (http://wbotelhos.com/raty) on my rails 4 app and it works fine localy. When I deploy to heroku I get this error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'raty' ". All other javascript works fine as well. I did precompile assets but it didn't help.

Comment: You're going to get that error if raty is not yet loaded on the page before you call `someRatyObject.someRatyMethod()`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to load at all and I don't understand why if it loads locally.

Comment: Are you using rails to handle dependency management? Or are you including a script include tag?